# MySQL Insert Incorrect CRC32 hash

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL table **products**, which has **url** and **url_crc** fields. I have incorrect CRC32 calculating at the time of insert.

> INSERT INTO products (url, url_crc) VALUES
>   ('http://www.zappos.com/product/7859366/color/106',
>   CRC32('http://www.zappos.com/product/7859366/color/106'))

Result is:
http://www.zappos.com/product/7859366/color/106, 2147483647

But when i do this:

> SELECT CRC32('http://www.zappos.com/product/7859366/color/106')

Result is: **2838206275**

Why is this happen ? `2838206275 != 2147483647`.

Triggers didn't help. Result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum value of a 32 bit signed integer is 2^31-1.

2838206275 is greater than that.

(2147483647 is conveniently 2^31-1).

In other words, use a larger data type (bigint).

Comment: The data type returned by the CRC32 function is INT UNSIGNED - I'd say you should use that rather than BIGINT, otherwise you're using twice as much space as you need to store the 32 bit CRCs.

Answer (score 1):

It was truncated by maximum value of `int` type.

Alter the url_crc column into `bigint` type.

`ALTER TABLE products MODIFY COLUMN url_crc BIGINT;`